# ReactPHP and EOT

Tags: php, reactive-programming, reactphp

When I close a terminal which is connected to a reactPHP socket I get many `data` events where the data consists of `EOT` signs (hex `04`):

```
event 1: 04040404
event 2: 04040404040404040404040404040404040404
event 3: 0404040404040404
event 4: 0404040404040404
event 5: 0404040404040404040404
event 6: 040404040404040404040404040404
event 7: 0404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404040404
event 8: 04040404040404040404
event 9: 04040404
```

What's the proper way to ignore them? They are useless because I can react on a transaction close by the `close` event of the connection itself.